# Pacing formula by hour rather than day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below formula which calculates the current pacing of a campaign based on the number of clicks currently achieved vs the number of clicks it is meant to achieve. For example, if the campaign is supposed to achieve 100 clicks over 10 days, but then only gets 5 clicks in the first day, it'll be pacing at 50%.

It works well, however the pacing is only calculated by day, whereas I'd like to do it by hour. How can I achieve this? I tried dividing by 24 but that went horribly wrong!

**Working (daily) formula below:**

`=SUM((S48/(Live!$B$1-G48 +1))*((H48-G48 +1)/K48))`

S48 = number of clicks currently achieved

B1 = todays date (e.g. 21/07/2020)

G48 = start date of campaign used for pacing formula

H48 = end date of campaign used for pacing formula

K48 = total number of clicks the campaign needs to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original formula, you don't need `SUM(`.

```
=(S48/(Live!$B$1-G48 +1))*((H48-G48 +1)/K48)
```

should work fine.

To make it work hourly, you'll need to make sure that B1 has the latest time and not just the latest date. You can automate that by using `=now()` instead of `today()`.

The hourly formula is:

```
=(S48/((Live!$B$1-G48 +1)*24)*(((H48-G48 +1)*24)/K48))
```